# Unity error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'value' of 'GameObject.SetActive(bool)'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MusicController : MonoBehaviour
{
public AudioClip gameMusic;

public AudioClip loseMusic;

public AudioClip winMusic;

public AudioSource musicSource;

public GameObject winText;

public GameObject loseText;

private int changed = 0;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        if (changed == 0)
        {
            musicSource.clip = gameMusic;

            musicSource.Play();

            changed = 1;
        }
        if (changed == 1)
        {
           if (winText.SetActive() == true) // line 42
            {
            musicSource.Stop();

            musicSource.clip = winMusic;

            musicSource.Play();
            
            changed = 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error

> Assets\Scripts\MusicController.cs(42,24): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'value' of 'GameObject.SetActive(bool)'

I've tried research more about what exactly this error means, but the other examples of it dont seem like they fit my case. I mainly want to know what to avoid so I never have an issue like this again.

Comment: Have you read the documentation as it seems pretty clear

Comment: Does setActive return a Boolean?

Comment: @BugFinder I just took a peek at it, but I'm not really grasping it.

Comment: @scottdavidwalker setActive is a boolean, I'm trying to find a way to make music trigger when the text is setActive(true) and appears on the screen

Comment: You can check my answer for what the actual issue is. I would check whether there is an “isActive” property that you can do your if statement on

Answer (score 0):

setActive accepts a Boolean as an argument but doesn’t have a return type. So your if statement can’t check a “void” against a “bool”.

[See the method signature here in the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html)